# Oreo 8.0 - How can I bypass root detection for banking app? - Suhide doesn't work

Tags: rooting, nexus-5x

So I just flashed suhide lite onto my nexus 5x after reading around that I could use it to bypass root detection for banking apps and android pay; however even if I set it so my banking app (halifax) can't detect root I open it up and it still states an error code about it being rooted.

Anyone able to help me figure out an alternative or if I'm missing something?

Comment: Chances are you failed the SafetyNet checks, that is why it is failing.  You would need to research Magisk, as this can not only hide su but also will not fail SafetyNet.

Comment: That's the wierd thing cause I have safetynet checks app installed and it passes it. I even tried virtualapp and parallel space and it would still show in banking app that it phone was rooted.

Surely though with magisk I would have to flash this and uninstall supersu?

Answer (score 3):

There're apps like VirtualApp, VirtualXposed and Parallel Space that can clone your apps into a "sandbox" environment. I've just tested cloning my root management app SuperSU into VirtualXposed and it didn't detect the device has been rooted.

I guess that banking apps may also fail to detect root, but it's not guaranteed. All those apps can be used free and VirtualApp **was** open sourced. VirtualXposed won't be available for you because banking apps detect not only root but also xposed.

**But anyway keep in mind that sandbox apps are always able to see all app's private data inside it.**

Answer (score 1):

Ended up switching over to Magisk instead and now it all works and can use android pay and halifax banking app by simply using magiskhide.